# How to replace radio button by drop down select in wordpress meta box field?

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-boxes

How to replace radio button by drop down select in wordpress meta box field ??

```
  <tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row"><label for="effectv">Select effect</label></th>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" id="effectv" name="b26slider_options[effectv]" <?php if($settings['effectv'] == 'zoomOut') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="zoomOut" />zoomOut
        <input type="radio" id="effectv" name="b26slider_options[effectv]" <?php if($settings['effectv'] == 'zoomIn') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="zoomIn" />zoomIn
        <input type="radio" id="effectv" name="b26slider_options[effectv]" <?php if($settings['effectv'] == 'panUp') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?> value="panUp" />panUp
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this and let me know it's work or not.

```
<tr valign="top">
    <th scope="row"><label for="effectv">Select effect</label></th>
    <td>
        <select name="b26slider_options[effectv]" id="effectv">
            <option value="zoomOut" <?php echo ($settings['effectv'] == "zoomOut") ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>zoomOut</option>
            <option value="zoomIn" <?php echo ($settings['effectv'] == "zoomIn") ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>zoomIn</option>
            <option value="panUp" <?php echo ($settings['effectv'] == "panUp") ? 'selected' : ''; ?>>panUp</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply replace them with the correct HTML.

```
<tr valign="top">
<th scope="row"><label for="effectv">Select effect</label></th>
<td>
<select name="select">
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
</td>
```

Click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) for more information.